# Compressor is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, android

Trying to compress an image using a [repository](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor).

I am following this tutorial [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdkTWOJCY5c&t=915s)

I have added the dependency and synced with no issues.

I have followed the instructions in the video carefully but still get the error.

I have tried re-syncing the dependency. And googled and found two solutions but neither worked for me.

```
compressedImageFile = new Compressor(Post_Tab.this)
                                .setMaxHeight(720)
                                .setMaxWidth(720)
                                .setQuality(50)
                                .compressToBitmap(newImageFile);
```

Comment: `new Compressor(this)` is using context as `this` parameter, is `Post_Tab.this` is a context? Then check if you're correctly import the library; `import id.zelory.compressor.Compressor;`

Answer (score 0):

By definition if a class is declared abstract, it cannot be instantiated.
To use an abstract class, you have to inherit it from another class and provide implementations to the abstract methods in it (if the abstract class has any abstract methods).